MuJoCo 2.0.2.7 Installation Error on python3.7 Virtual Environment - Cython
I am reproducing the code of safety-starter-agents. To fulfill the requirements in the setup.py file, I am running the code in a virtual environment on which python3.7 is running. This python version is compatible with all required packages versions.
In particular, I downloaded the required MuJoCo 2.0.2.7 from here. I added the mjkey.txt to the ~/.mujoco directory. I added the EXPORT-path to the ~/.bashrc following this tutorial
I am running the code on WSL Ubuntu 24.04.
When I run pip install mujoco_py==2.0.2.7, I am getting the following error:

Building wheels for collected packages: mujoco_py
Building wheel for mujoco_py (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for mujoco_py (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [95 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
performance hint: mujoco_py/cymj.pyx:67:5: Exception check on 'c_warning_callback' will always require the GIL to be acquired.
Possible solutions:
1. Declare 'c_warning_callback' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
2. Use an 'int' return type on 'c_warning_callback' to allow an error code to be returned.
performance hint: mujoco_py/cymj.pyx:104:5: Exception check on 'c_error_callback' will always require the GIL to be acquired.
Possible solutions:
1. Declare 'c_error_callback' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
2. Use an 'int' return type on 'c_error_callback' to allow an error code to be returned.
  Error compiling Cython file:
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  ...
      See c_warning_callback, which is the C wrapper to the user defined function
      '''
      global py_warning_callback
      global mju_user_warning
      py_warning_callback = warn
      mju_user_warning = c_warning_callback
                         ^
  ------------------------------------------------------------

  mujoco_py/cymj.pyx:92:23: Cannot assign type 'void (const char *) except * nogil' to 'void (*)(const char *) noexcept nogil'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to the type of 'c_warning_callback'.

  Error compiling Cython file:
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  ...
      See c_warning_callback, which is the C wrapper to the user defined function
      '''
      global py_error_callback
      global mju_user_error
      py_error_callback = err_callback
      mju_user_error = c_error_callback
                       ^
  ------------------------------------------------------------

  mujoco_py/cymj.pyx:127:21: Cannot assign type 'void (const char *) except * nogil' to 'void (*)(const char *) noexcept nogil'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to the type of 'c_error_callback'.
  Removing old mujoco_py cext /tmp/pip-install-nineq6nn/mujoco-py_1f5e0ced38f24aaea6fba7e65c0b6efd/mujoco_py/generated/cymj_2.0.2.7_37_linuxcpuextensionbuilder_37.so
  Compiling /tmp/pip-install-nineq6nn/mujoco-py_1f5e0ced38f24aaea6fba7e65c0b6efd/mujoco_py/cymj.pyx because it changed.
  [1/1] Cythonizing /tmp/pip-install-nineq6nn/mujoco-py_1f5e0ced38f24aaea6fba7e65c0b6efd/mujoco_py/cymj.pyx

I tried the suggested solutions in this link. However, changing Cython versions is not working in this specific setting.
I was able to successfully download other versions of MuJoCo on this same virtual environment. MuJoCo 2.0.2.7 is delivering this error.
Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this error?

It'll almost certainly be because pip is using isolated environments - when you try to install mujoco_py it sets up an empty virtual environment, installs Cython 3 (because it isn't pinned in https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/blob/master/pyproject.toml) and then uses that.

@DavidW Thank you for your explanation. I tried to set constraints on Cython installation version "cython<3" in a separate 'constraints.txt' file and ran the following command 'pip install mujoco_py==2.0.2.7 -c ./constraints.txt'. It did not solve the problem. Do you think it is possible to successfully reproduce the code in my settings? If yes, could you please give me hints? I am working on Ubuntu 24.04

I'm slightly surprised that the constraints didn't work. You'd probably want to run pip in as verbose mode as possible and see what it is installing
